# Complement of the directed graph

Tags: graph-theory, definition, directed-graphs

What is a formal way to define a complement of a directed graph? On the wikipedia link -> [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_graph#:~:text=In%20graph%20theory%2C%20the%20complement,are%20not%20adjacent%20in%20G.&text=It%20is%20not%2C%20however%2C%20the,only%20the%20edges%20are%20complemented.) it is not quite clear for me if we take the edges of the opposite direction. In any case, could anyone please clearly give a definition of the complement of the directed graph?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Say we have a directed graph $D=(V,A)$. 
Let $A_{all}$ denote the set of all possible directed edges on the vertex set $V$. In other words, if $u$ and $v$ are vertices of $V$, then **both** the directed edges $u\rightarrow v$ and $v \rightarrow u$ belong to $A_{all}$.

The complement of $D$ will be the directed graph $\overline{D} = (V, A_{all}\setminus A)$. In other words, the complement has every possible directed edge not in $D$.

The directed graph formed by reversing the direction of all the edges in $D$ is the **transpose** or **reverse** of $D$, and is in general not the same as the complement.

See this link:
[Wikipedia - Transpose of Digraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose_graph)

Comment: Nice answer. Just to elucidate a bit, the only time the complement and the transpose will be the same is when $D$ is a tournament (an oriented complete graph; can the OP see why?). If $D$ is a simple digraph which isn't a tournament, then $\overline{D}$ will have "multiple directed edges" between some pair of vertices, i.e. a pair of vertices $u, v$ with both arcs $u \rightarrow v$ and $v \rightarrow u$ present. Since the graph $(V(D), A_{all})$ has $2\binom{n}{2} = n(n - 1)$ arcs (in a digraph of order n; why?), we have that $\lvert A(\overline{D}) \rvert = n(n - 1) - \lvert A(D) \rvert$.