# Binary negated graph

Tags: graph-theory

This is question out of curiosity.

Recently I am working with graphs (and directed graphs), and found out that I need a condition that the elementwise negated adjacency matrix has only one strongly connected component.

I searched a little bit the literature, but found nothing about negated adjacency matrices. Can someone point me to some literature maybe? I cannot believe no one studied this before.

Comment: Is this not the same as the complement of the digraph?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3705154/complement-of-the-directed-graph

Comment: Thats it. Thank you.